# Gnuplot 3d plot too high

Tags: gnuplot

I have this plot
[image: plot]
And as you can see, there's this gap between the zero and the bottom of the plot, is it possible to move the plot down so the 0 is at the bottom?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Use:

```
set xyplane at 0
```

to remove the offset.

On older gnuplot, you may need to use:

```
set ticslevel 0
```

instead.

Answer (score -1):

I can't really test it without your data, but did you try to set the limits on the axis? if not set manually, octave sometimes takes liberties to shift the data.

https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Axis-Configuration.html

Comment: I have set the axises manually with the `set [xyz]range` commands.

Comment: What does this have to do with gnuplot?