# Double 0 point in splot Z axis

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to plot 3D graph in gnuplot, but Z axis shows 0 points for 2 times that looks very strange. How to move z=0 plane higher? 
[image: splot graph]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25084867/2604213

Comment: Thanks, quite hard to formulate a problem here..